# jQuery $.get does nothing in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, get

This question seems to have been asked before, but I can't find a conclusive answer to it.

I am using `$.get()` on document ready to fire a Facebook Events query.

Works fine in every browser, except IE (I am using IE9.0, both normally or in compatibility mode)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + k + "&client_secret=" + sc + "&grant_type=client_credentials", function (result) {
         // DO STUFF //
    });
});
```

Before you shout at me for using a FB client secret in code, it's not a production application, I'm just trying to build a method to quickly get access tokens.

Anyway... in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, this does exactly what it should. However, in IE it does nothing, the function is not fired. It's not a cache issue, or an issue with the headers of the request page (as has been mentioned in other posts) as it is an issue with triggering the function.

---

EDIT, to clarify as I had a typo initially. Here's actual code that I've tried to run (taken on board the suggestion to use `&amp;` instead of `&`

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + k + "&amp;client_secret=" + sc + "&amp;grant_type=client_credentials", function (result) {
        alert("got token") 
    });
});
```

The alert is not being fired.

Comment: The syntax is off (you have two closing braces for the success callback). Is that a typo or does the original code read like this too?

Comment: Argh... sorry, yes, amended, that was a typo. There are no syntax errors in my original code.

Comment: Don't replace `&` with `&amp;`. That's HTML escaping which has absolutely nothing to do with this situation. Can you use a sniffing tool such as Fiddler to see if IE is trying to access that URL?

Comment: Well that's really odd! I've not used Fiddler before. Generally just do things with Firebug. However, Fiddle doesn't show any activity to the FB graph, but some elements are clearly working!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE, but there is a braces typo:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + k + "&client_secret=" + sc + "&grant_type=client_credentials", function (result) {
            // DO STUFF //
    });
});
```

Also you might consider replacing `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: Sorry, the braces error was a typo, I'll try the &amp; change though... not sure it'll work though as it doesnt appear to even be firing the `$.get()` function at all.

Comment: Can you give us the context of the code. Where it resides, where jQuery is included, etc.

Comment: Why would you replace `&` with `&amp;`? This is JavaScript, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works. Gets the access token and uses it to fetch the feed:

```
$.get("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=CLIENT_ID_HERE&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_HERE", function (a, b, c) {
    $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/barackobama/feed?" + a, function (a, b, c) {
        $.each(a.data, function (i, item) {
            $("#facebook").append('</br>' + (item.story == null ? item.message : item.story));
        });
    });
});
```

client_id and client_secret are the App ID and App Secret of the App.

You can get these from the App on Facebook developers.